# Windows 7 network printer to automatically print to a folder on the server

Tags: windows-7, networking, printing, network-printer

I manage a small cyber cafe at a library and we want printing support for all the clients on the public network.

However, most of the equipment that we have access to doesn't allow any form of authentication or print spooling so that someone doesn't overload a printer.

Is there a printer driver that can print a file to a network folder for, say a librarian to see and check before printing but that's seamless and doesn't ask where to store those files?

Comment: You can print a file to xls format and send it to librarian network drive. Let him take a look and let him initiate a print.

Comment: that's not really an option sadly, it's needs to be a bit more streamlined because the XPS document writer asks for where to put the file and i can't possibly be in the building all the time to show people.

Comment: My local library manages this quite effectively by charging for each printed page. If people are paying to print they will soon learn not to overload the printer ;)

Comment: we do charge but Lack of accountability is a problem unfortunetly :/ when the printer prints regardless of checking if the document is sensible to print then what's to stop someone coming in, printing a 200 page document and running out the door. that's why really we need the system in place so the librarians can check it.

Comment: Or get a pay-up-front system.

Comment: that's not a bad idea, wouldn't be out of the question to physically disconnect the printer until someone wants to print. think i may have a solution actually, i'll post a solution when i've got it worked out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone, I've managed to solve the problem myself though.

What i ended up doing was using redmon http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/ and installing a PS printer driver that was redirected into that. Then i had RedMon save a PDF file to a Network share that was shared via the Librarians Machine. Then have the printer installed on there.

[Redirected port options i ended up using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGj1f.png)

RedMon actually does all this in the background, which is perfect because i don't want people to see it.

The only issues i've had have been to do with Fileshare permissions, but i'll soldier on with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a port that points to a specified file name. To create the port, go to Printer Properties > Ports and create a new "Local Port".

Printer spool files are not normally viewable, so use the XPS driver to get a printer-ready file that is viewable by the librarian. Alternatively, you can use a PostScript driver (if the printer supports it) and use GhostSCript to view the file.

You should be also running a script that renames the file immediately immediately after creation (e.g. with a time stamp), to avoid duplication.